# Chart.js size not adapting to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried so many things (modify css, add inline css to canvas, add inline css to a wrapper div of canvas) but I still can't make the chart fit in the panel properly.

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
        <section class="panel">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                Temp
            </header>
                <canvas id="tempChart"></canvas>
        </section>
```

Here is the js code

```
<script>

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "Aary", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0)',
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: 'red',
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    } ]
};

var option = {
    responsive: true,

};

var ctx = $("#tempChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, option);
```

The class panel in CSS contains only graphic things such as border background color and so on.
By the way I am using Bootstrap grid.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you add a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: have you tried to set all your charts responsive with default value : Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;

Comment: Is this v1 of chartjs?

Comment: Have you tried   ctx.height and ctx.width propert? like:
  ctx.height = 20;
  ctx.width = 80;
It will set width and height for your canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set all your charts responsive with default value : `Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;`

Your global synthax seems correct has you setted up

```
var options = { responsive:true }
```

However; it's a tiny detail but you added a coma after that true. 
I suggest to remove it.

as @brian suggested; please; inform us the version of the lib.
Add a jsfindle is even better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. The problem was the version of lib I was using. Updating that solved the problem.